# sqlalchemy engine multiple databases with mysql

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I tried a few different things but I could not succeed, so maybe it's just not possible.

When I create a sqlalchemy engine with

```
 create_engine('mysql://user@host/database')
```

it looks like the database is compulsory, while it's not using the sqlite backend.
But since I have to manipulate many different databases on the same server, I would like to avoid creating multiple engines..

Is there a way?
Otherwise what I could is to create a superengine that creates all the needed engines and then redirect to the right engine depending on the database name requested...

Answer (score 0):

One engine pretty much equals one connectable database. [See SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/engines.html). You can have as many engines as you want, or you can throw away the engines that you do not need anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the engine one time for each of your databases would be the way I would do it. The you will be able to access them as needed instead of creating an engine then destroying it then recreating etc.